What is the corresponding filtration of the martingale $M(t) =N(t)-\int_0^t \lambda(v) Y(v) \,d v$?
I have found three different expressions of the filtration corresponding to the quantity $M(t) =N(t)-\int_0^t \lambda(v) Y(v) \,d v$:
Here is the first one: define $N_T(t)=I(T \leq t)$ and $Y_T(t) = I\{T\ge t\}$.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma\left\{N_T(u), Y_T\left(u^+\right), Z ; 0 \leq u \leq t\right\}
\end{align}
I found it in the paper Luo, Xu "Doubly robust inference for hazard ratio under informative censoring with machine learning" (2022). Specifically, after their equation (2) on page 4. Same notation is found here page 12 as well.
Here is the second one: define $X=\min(T,C)$, and $\delta = I(T<C)$.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma\left\{I_{\{X \leq u, \delta=1\}}, I_{\{X \leq u, \delta=0\}}: 0 \leq u \leq t\right\}
\end{align}
I found it in the book Fleming, T.R. and Harrington, D.P. (1991). Chapter 1.3 The martingale $M=N-A$ on page 25.
Here is the third one:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(I(T \leq u), I(C \leq v): u \leq t, v \leq t)
\end{align}
This comes from my survival class lecture, which is not posted on any public site. But I can quote the slide

Recall the counting process notation we introduced before, including $N(t), Y(t)$, without covariate $Z$ for the time being. Let $A(t)=\int_0^t \alpha(u) d u=\int_0^t Y(u) \lambda(u) d u . A(t)$ is called the compensator of $N(t)$. Define $\mathcal{F}_t$ the $\sigma$-algebra (set of sets) or filtration that represents all the information (history) up to time $t$. More precisely, let
$$
\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(I(T \leq u), I(C \leq v): u \leq t, v \leq t)
$$
Then, it can be shown (next page) that
$$
M(t)=N(t)-A(t)
$$
is a ${\text { martingale }}$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$, i.e. $E\left\{M(t) \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-}\right\}=M(t-)$, or equivalently, $E\left\{d {\left.M(t) \mid \mathcal{F}_{t-}\right\}}=0\right.$, where $d M(t)=M(t)-M(t-)$.

The first and the third filtration are generated by indicators that are not fully observed, while the second filtration are generated by indicators written in terms of $X$ and $\delta$, which are observable. May I ask which filtration is the most appropriate to work with?
So far we are talking under the independent censoring assumption $T \!\perp\!\!\!\perp C$. However, suppose $T \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp  C$, what would be the most appropriate filtration to work with?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please edit the question to specify the sources for your three formulas? It's possible that each is correct, or even equivalent, depending on the context in which each result was presented.

Thank you! Sure just did.

The first one you give is explicitly defined in the paper you  link as the full data filtration, ie, the filtration in the absence of censoring. They want that for the IPCW argument.  In that paper, as they note just after equation 4, the process called $M$ isn't necessarily a martingale with respect to the observable history. Further, $M_c$, the mean-centered censoring counting process is defined as a martingale with respect to its observed history.
This all gives less disagreement with Fleming & Harrington's definition, which is the filtration based on the observable history.
In my experience, if you are genuinely going to take advantage of the fact that $$M(t)= N(t)-\textit{something}(t)$$ is a martingale then you will want it to be a martingale with respect to an observable filtration.  But it's less common to rely on martingale properties for inference nowadays than it was when Fleming & Harrington wrote.
